# Why Java Enumeration doesn't return properties list in order?

Tags: java

I'm creating a simple program with the possibility to change the language and I would convert the list of properties in the file myBundle.properties in a String array.

This is the file myBundle.properties:

```
 #default
 test1=Hello1
 test2=Hello2
 test3=Hello3
 test4=Hello4
 test5=Hello5
 test6=Hello6
```

And this is the Java code:

```
import java.util.*;

class BundleTest {

    BundleTest() {
        String[] s = returnStringArray(Locale.ENGLISH);
        for(int i=0; i<s.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(s[i]);
        }
    }

    private String[] returnStringArray(Locale language) {
        try {
            ResourceBundle labels = ResourceBundle.getBundle("myBundle", language);
            Enumeration<String> keys = labels.getKeys();
            Vector v = new Vector();
            String key = null;
            while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
                v.add(keys.nextElement());
            }
            String[] s = new String[v.size()];
            for(int i=0; i<s.length; i++) {
                s[i] = (String)v.elementAt(i);
            }
            return s;
        } catch (MissingResourceException mre) {
            System.out.println("Risorse della lingua non trovate!");
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BundleTest();
    }
}
```

But, surprisingly, when I execute the program it returns me the strings in a casual order. Why have Enumeration this strange behavior?

```
bash-4.1$ java BundleTest
test1
test6
test4
test5
test2
test3
```

Comment: I believe Vector is deprecated, by the way.  Checking out Vector's javadoc will point you to supported alternatives.  (Sorry to sidetrack the issue.)

Comment: Where does it say that `ResourceBundle.getKeys()` returns an *ordered* enumeration? Thsi has nothing to do with `Enumeration`, but the source behind which is probably a `Set` and thereby not preserving any order.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do not know the exact details of the ResourceBundle class, but when looking at your code example, it seems that it has key/value pairs.

This suggests that it stores its content in an [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). (Again, as I do not know ResounrceBundle, this is a hunch)
HashMap keys (and values) are unordered as they are stored on such a way that the value can be easily found for a given key.

Comment: indeed, doesn't HashMap place added elements based on it's hashKey?

Answer (score 3):

Se if replacing

```
Enumeration<String> keys = labels.getKeys();
```

with

```
List<String> keys =  Collections.list( labels.getKeys() );
Collections.sort(keys);
```

helps

Comment: I think the objective is to sort by the order they in the property file, not by the "natural" order of the keys.

Comment: its the same order in the provided example.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you are getting back a [PropertyResourceBundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PropertyResourceBundle.html), which internally uses a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) for storage. HashMaps are not ordered.

This is because ResourceBundles should be used for retrieving value by key, not for enumerating in sorted order based on the original property file.

Answer (score 0):

There are two places where I would not assume the order.
1.From the Vector and 
2.labels.getKeys();

Try it on a enum that is not instantiated by a collection.