# When I am fetching the values from property file using ResourceBundle,I get the values in random order

Tags: java, enumeration, resourcebundle

When I am fetching the values from property file using ResourceBundle,I get the values in random order. I would like to get the values in its original order as it is given in the properties file..Can anyone help in getting the values in as it is order.

```
        while (bundleKeys.hasMoreElements()) {
            key = (String)bundleKeys.nextElement();
            int  k = key.indexOf(key, 0);
            System.out.println("---------"+k);
            if (key.startsWith(prefixMatch) ) {
                 logger.info( rb.getString(key) );
                 result= rb.getString(key);
            }

        }
```

Comment: values in prop file for e.g : 
host.server.sitA.ster.1=9.124.72.160:50959
host.server.sitA.ster.2=9.124.72.160:50967
host.server.sitB.ster.1=9.124.72.160:137
host.server.sitB.ster.2=9.124.72.160:123

Below is the code i have use .I think the problem is when i use enumeration.

        while (bundleKeys.hasMoreElements()) {
        key = (String)bundleKeys.nextElement();
        int  k = key.indexOf(key, 0);
        System.out.println("---------"+k);
          if (key.startsWith(prefixMatch) ) {
          logger.info( rb.getString(key) );
          result= rb.getString(key);
          }
     }

Comment: while (bundleKeys.hasMoreElements()) {
          key = (String)bundleKeys.nextElement();
          int  k = key.indexOf(key, 0);
          System.out.println("---------"+k);
          if (key.startsWith(prefixMatch) ) {
            logger.info( rb.getString(key) );
            result= rb.getString(key);
          }

      }

Comment: Why don't you use the `Properties` class? And why is it a problem that the keys are not in the order as they are in the file?

Comment: we are using resourcebundle ..so we cant change it to properties class now.. any code which can fetch the elements in its original order as given in file

Comment: And why is it a problem? You usually request a single item from a `ResourceBundle` so I don't get what the problem is.

Comment: from the above while loop i should get values in this order
9.124.72.160:50959
9.124.72.160:50967
9.124.72.160:137
9.124.72.160:123
1.0.0.1:123
127.0.0.1:8080
127.0.0.1:10556
127.0.0.1:33333
127.0.0.1:52012
127.0.0.1:52013
184.85.52.26:80
but i m getting the values in random order... not like above

Comment: Again: ***why*** is that a problem? What are you really trying to achieve? Why do you *need* them to be in the correct order? How do you use that bundle in your code so that the order matters?

Comment: Bro I had explained everything in above code and desciption .. its a very basic and simple thing tht we are trying to acheive .. i wonder how u are not able to understand this simple query...

Comment: These are the key value pairs .. 
host.server.sitA.ster.1=9.124.72.160:50959 host.server.sitA.ster.2=9.124.72.160:50967 host.server.sitB.ster.1=9.124.72.160:137 host.server.sitB.ster.2=9.124.72.160:123
from above properties file we are getting values using ResourceBundle class.. and using enumeration we are getting the elements from resourcebundle.. but unfortunately they are not comeing in the order given above.. they are coming in random order .. I cant be more clear and specific then this... thanks

Comment: @user3048947 Please incorporate all your comments into the question. It is very difficult for anyone to follow your thoughts with the limited formatting of comments. You make it easier for the people that you are asking for help.

Comment: @user3048947 regarding the order of the properties. As I can see the property keys end with a number. My assumption is that you can use this number to order the values in your preferred order ("smaller to bigger" or "bigger to smaller"). So what is the problem of having to sort the value in your code?

Answer (score 0):

See this post about this subject: 
[Why Java Enumeration doesn't return properties list in order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085994/why-java-enumeration-doesnt-return-properties-list-in-order)

Internal HashMap or Set provided by ResourceBundle are not ordered.

Assuming this data:

```
host.server.sitA.ster.1=9.124.72.160:50959 
host.server.sitA.ster.2=9.124.72.160:50967 
host.server.sitB.ster.1=9.124.72.160:137 
host.server.sitB.ster.2=9.124.72.160:123
```

Why not loading your IP using the wanted key as usual with a ResourceBundle:

```
ResourceBundle ipBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(myBundleName);
String ipSitA = ipBundle.getString("host.server.sitA.ster.1");
```