# Why can't I read .properties file in order?

Tags: java, properties-file

I have a label.properties file like this:

```
text1:firstname
text2:middlename
text3:lastname
text4:username
```

I read the properties file using this code

```
package test;

import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;


public class labelclass {

    public static String read(int n) {

        ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("myfolder.label");
        Enumeration <String> keys = rb.getKeys();
        while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
            for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
                    String key = keys.nextElement();
            }
            String value = rb.getString(key);
            return value;
        }
    }

}
```

If I call `read(2)`, It should return `middlename`. But it returns `firstname`
The order at which it returns is like:

```
text2:middlename
text1:firstname
text4:username
text3:lastname
```

Why is this so?

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11087065/180100) for a possible solution

Comment: @RC I actually made a quick search.. Was not able to find this..

Comment: @rey-rajash no problem, this is the way SO is supposed to work IMHO ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.properties` files are loaded by [ResourceBundle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) into a [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), which does not preserve order. The [Enumeration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html) object that you receive is just an iterator over the set.

I looked into the [ListResourceBundle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListResourceBundle.html) class and unfortunately it too returns an Enumeration object over a set that does not maintain order.

**Edit**: `.properties` will be loaded using [InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) in [PropertyResourceBundle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PropertyResourceBundle.html) and stored in an instance of [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) that is internally represented by a [Hashtable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) which too does not maintain order. So the order is lost quite early in the process and several times later on.

Comment: Actually, it's Hashtable...

Comment: The relevant Properties class extends Hashtable, not HashSet.

Answer (score 2):

`ResourceBundle` works on a `Set`, which is inherently not ordered in any way. You can retrieve all element and it guarantees that there are no duplicate elements, but it does not conserve any order of elements.

This is why you can't access an element by its number and have to resort to your for loop. Sets are not meant to be accessed in an indexed fashion.